# How to use sendmail with Laravel?

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, laravel-5, sendmail

I have tested a password reset feature on Laravel 5.5 using mailtrap.io.

I use these credentials in the `.env` file:

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=**
MAIL_PASSWORD=**
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
Auth=PLAIN
```

It works okay. However, I now need to deploy it to an Ubuntu server which already has a configured `sendmail` package, but what settings do I need to include in the `.env` file?

The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail) does mention sendmail, but what's an example set of settings?

Answer (score 8):

for using sendmail drivers you need to set driver parameter in your `.env` file

i.e.

```
#.env

...
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_SENDMAIL='/your/sendmail/path -with -parameters'
...
```

rest of the configurations are set in sendmail

P.S. make sure your sendmail path is same as the default `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs` or also provide that in `.env` file and change this in `config/mail.php`

```
'sendmail' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs')
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Laravel 7
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail

has been replaced with

MAIL_MAILER=sendmail

If you don't make the change the system will go to the config/mail.php default, usually smtp and you will encounter things like Relay error messages as it isn't using the intended driver.

There is no supplied backwards compatible alias in Laravel 7.